# Should a semicolon be used in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

Is the following sentence correct?

> Ellie disagreed, saying, “Foot fungus is much more fun than learning
>   words.”

Specifically, should there be a semicolon somewhere before the quote?

Comment: Why do you think there should be? _saying_ is just a participle set off by commas.

Comment: Avoid proofreading or rewriting requests. “How should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, and “which is correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”

Answer (score 2):

Keep the punctuation as it stands because the second clause is a *dependent clause*. You would use a semicolon, however, if the sentence was written as two independent clauses, such as:

> Ellie disagreed; she said, "Foot fungus..."

Answer (score 0):

I would use a colon not a semi colon right after disagreed.  This way it is all one sentence.